# Mistaken Connect 5V to SCK Pin

Tags: atmega328, oscillator-clock, usbasp

i have old chinese old hotair station that controls by atmega8l 8ua chip..
and the board designer are clever enough to put 2 identical dc plug, 1 is 5v supply cable.. the other one is on off switch that connect ground pin to sck pin..

i was mistaken plug power cable to the on off side that supply 5v+  to sck.. now the station not powering up anymore..

is there anyway to copy the firmware to new chip?
it cannot be detected by usbasp since i believes the sck are toasted..

i'm just a beginners and English are not my native language. sorry if the word are hard to understand..

Comment: Welcome to Arduino! Please take the [tour](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Retrieving the software from this AVR is - with any reasonably amount of effort - rather unlikely. It'll be easierer to guess the function of it and rewrite a "similar" software from scratch.

Comment: Both serial and parallel programming modes seem to require the SCK pin.

Comment: thanks for both of You.. i think the station manufacture intended to make the port identical to destroying they product if someone try tampered their product.. so there is no chance to duplicate the firmware as Gerben told that both connections required sck pin.. As Ghanima solution to rewrite similar software from scratch it's seem a little difficult to me.. i'm totally noob about arduino, i brought the uno couple of years ago for calibrate drone esc board. then i have never touch the uno again.. i think i need to dig deeper..